# popen equivalent in c++

Tags: c++, posix, popen

Is their any C **popen()** equivalent in C++ ?

Comment: Notice that `popen` is *not* a function prescribed by the *[C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) standard*. It is in POSIX, so it is available in your C++ code for POSIX systems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the "not yet official" [boost.process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) if you want an object-oriented approach for managing the subprocess.

Or you can just use `popen` itself, if you don't mind the C-ness of it all.

Answer (score 9):

There is no C++ equivalent in any Standard, however C++ wrappers around this function (and other POSIX process function) can be found in various UI Toolkit (e.g [QT](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qprocess.html), [glibmm](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glibmm/unstable/group__Spawn.html)) and in the [pstreams library](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 6):

C++ is a superset of C.  `popen` is available to C++ code as well.

Comment: I don't think that popen is required by the Standard.

Comment: Which standard?  popen comes from POSIX.1-2001.  Even Windows has a POSIX-compatibility layer.  Linux and MacOS support it natively, of course.  It's a library function, not part of the C standard itself.

Comment: popen() is part of POSIX, so any UNIX-like operating system should support it.  Even for non-POSIX OSes, if you have popen() in C, you should be able to use it in C++, unless there's something very wrong with your compiler.

Comment: Technically, C++ isn't a superset of C.

Comment: I know popen is available in c++. But I am flexible C++ iostream.

Comment: @You: Saying C++ isn't a superset of C is like saying Python 3.0 isn't a superset of Python 2.7.  While technically true, it's not useful to anyone but pedantics trying to start an argument

Comment: @Danny: But it is true. And the minimal effort required to write "C++ is, *for all intents and purposes*, a superset of C" is totally worth it.

Comment: @BlueRaja: I agree that in most cases it can be considered a superset, but there are some things that are supported in C and not in C++, like arrays whose size is defined at runtime: `void f( int x ) { int a[x]; }` And there are subtleties, like `void f(); void f( int i ) {}` in C defines a single function that takes an argument, in C++ it declares a function with no arguments and an overload with one argument...

Comment: @David: Arrays whose size is defined at runtime is not an exactly well supported item in C.

Comment: @Billy: Visual Studio is the only compiler I know of that has no C99 support --and probably never will. The rest of the compilers I know (gcc, intel, sun, comeau) all have support for variable size arrays. Whether a single vendor make it *not exactly well supported* is debatable, kind of *POSIX is not a well supported standard*, as there are some OS that don't comply with it.

Comment: C++ is absolutely *not* a superset of C.

Comment: @Blue what? "Python 3.0 isn't a superset of Python 2.7" <- that's true and it's a useful statement to do. I don't get your point. I doubt that python 3 differs by the degree C++ differs from C though. Much features of C aren't present in C++ and vice versa.