# How to list threads opened by every application in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

Is there a way to know, at a real time, what threads are opened and what application opened them?

Comment: Ubuntu usually means Linux :)

Comment: @Nikolai my bad, I totally mis-read the tags, sry.

Comment: Night Walker, please, do not narrow your questions unnecessarily.  Ubuntu is only one variant of Linux, and there's nothing in this system what makes *programming* different.  On SuperUser or ServerFault it would be ok separating it from the other Linuxes.  However, when talking about generic Linux *programming* questions, Ubuntu makes no difference.  *Especially* if you do not specify [linux] tag as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can look in `/proc/<PID>/task/` (where `<PID>` is a process-ID) which will have a number of subdirectories, each with the name equal to the thread-ID of one of the threads in that task.

Note that this is only sort-of real-time though -- unless you were to "freeze" the entire system for the duration, the information you get can always be stale, because a process may create or destroy threads even as you're looking at the data.

Answer (score 4):

In modern Linuxes, threads are very much like processes.  Each thread has an LWP ("light-weight process") identifier, which is internally implemented as PID.   However, if such "light-weight process" (i.e. thread) is queried for a PID, the system yields the PID of the process that spawned the thread (instead of LWP).  Note also, that if the process has only one thread, it's LWP will be equal to its PID.

`ps` is capable to processing threads with `-L` modifier, as [ereOn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279259/ereon) described in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290408/threads-opened-by-every-application/3290481#3290481).  But I should note that `ps` is not just for manual invocation.  It has capabilities to print output in such a way that's easy to parse by another program.

The following command will print LWPs (`-o lwp=`) and PIDs (`-o pid=`) of all (`-A`) threads (`-L`) in the system.  Each string represents one thread, second column being the process that spawned it:

```
$ ps -A -L -o lwp= -o pid=
...
27747 27747
27749 27749
27750 27750
27751 27750
27752 27750
27755 27750
27756 27750
27772 27772
27858 27858
30457 30457
30886 30886
```

Quite easy to parse with C or C++, isn't it?  To actually read this from your program, you can use [`popen`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html#tag_03_420_06) or one of its [C++ equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190514/popen-equivalent-in-c).

Note that using `ps` is not only easier than reading `/proc`.  It's also much safer than manually parsing `/proc` filesystem.  `ps` is a POSIX command*, it's guaranteed to work; it does use `/proc` under Linux, but that's internal details.  When underlying infrastructure changes, `ps` will be rewritten, and will keep working, while your code, if written based on `/proc`, will break.

---

*To be honest, POSIX does not specify `-L` switch.  But in any Linux, which has GNU toolchain, it will be available.

Answer (score 3):

I guess `ps -L` should do the trick.

Here is `ps`[documentation](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=p/ps).

Not sure if you ask how to do that programmaticaly, but in this case, since `ps` is open-source, so you can probably take a look at the sources.

Comment: Not sure in what language i am going to implement so .

Comment: I'm sure any language you implement in will be capable of calling `ps`.