# Storing all the subdirectories

Tags: c++, unix, operating-system, posix

I am doing my assignment and would like to store all sub directories in the proc directory. One option is to use a file to store all and later store it back to a string like this.

```
 system("ls -1 /proc | sort > hw4data.txt "); 

    myFile.open("hw4data.txt");     
    myFile >> fdata;
```

But I am not allowed to use an extra file. But I want the list of all subdirectories in the /proc directory.

Comment: Do you want  to `store` or to `sort`?

Comment: I want to store the sorted list of all sub directories. Thanks though!

Comment: So if you don't want to use an extra file, what do you want  to use?

Comment: like an vector of strings where each entry is the name of the subdirectory.

Comment: You might want to look up (for one example) Boost [directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator).

Comment: You can use `popen()` to execute a shell command and read the output from it. Then you can read each line into a string, which you put into an array.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190514/popen-equivalent-in-c for C++ equivalents to `popen()`.

Comment: @Barmar, I have already a pipe set up between the child and the parent. The parent should send each subdirectory name to the child. How can I again use the popen(),? Thanks though!

Comment: The child can substitute the directory name into the `ls` command, and then call `popen()` with that command to read the output.